# write a script to spawn to R1(Router) and execute some commands on R1,and then you spawn to R2 and execute some commands on R1 again

Tags: switch-statement, expect, spawn

i am new to expect scripting please can any one help on this question.i know how to connect to   router 1 but if another router is added means how to connect to another router and how to execute commands on them

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set user "admin"
set pwd "lab"

set IP1 [lindex $argv 0] 
set Cons1 [lindex $argv 1]
set IP2 [lindex $argv 2]
set Cons2 [lindex $argv 3]


#Login to the first router
spawn telnet $IP1 $Cons1
set rtr1 $spawn_id  # Saving the spawn id into the variable 'rtr1'


#Login to the first router
spawn telnet $IP2 $Cons2
set rtr2 $spawn_id # Saving the spawn id into the variable 'rtr2'


expect -i $rtr1 "Login:" #This will expect 'Login' for the router 1
expect -i $rtr2 "Login:" #This will expect 'Login' for the router 2
send -i $rtr1 "$user\r" #This will send username to the router 1
send -i $rtr2 "$user\r" #This will send username to the router 2
expect -i $rtr1 "Password"
expect -i $rtr2 "Password"
send -i $rtr1 "$pass\r"
send -i $rtr2 "$pass\r"
expect -i $rtr1 -re ">"
expect -i $rtr2 -re ">"


#Do further operations
```

Please remember to include the the spawn process id variable for each `send` and `expect` operations along with `-i` option.